# How to add compile and commit time to a Svelte app?

Tags: svelte

I am developing a Svelte app prototype that gets deployed to GitHub on push using a GitHub action. As deployment can take a while, I would like to add the date and time of the last commit and the compilation of the app by Svelte to my HTML page, so I see whether my bugfix or new feature is available already for testing outside of my local development machine. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Could you put it in rollup or svelte.config.cjs (if using sveltekit)?

Get the time from Date() , export it as a variable on build, and consume it with svelte on the front. I believe, although crude, this could be done in either of those config files.

Comment: @Dapper: I don't use sveltekit and I don't want to depend on rollup, because I've heard that Svelte is going to discontinue using rollup in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you don not want to depend on rollup. Why not update the package,json (patch) version on the command line:

npm version patch -m "Upgrade to %s for reasons"

and read the version in your svelle app. Example main.js

```
import App from './App.svelte';
import { name, version } from '../package.json';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        packageJson: { name, version },
    },
});

export default app;
```

Comment: I did not know that you can import JSON files in Svelte, thanks!